# How to hide important string variable values in exe

Tags: c#

I want to hide important string variable values like passwords,username,ip and url,etc in .Net application (C#,VB.NET)
In process explorer we can view string in image or Memory ,**I want to hide image string**

[image]

Comment: please show some source code... what exactly is your goal ? what have you tried ? what is your "risk scenario" ? Are the potential attackers in your scenario "normal users" or "sophisticated hackers" ?

Comment: Basically - you can't. .NET code will always be discoverable. You would need to properly encrypt your string - but that again would require a decryption key that would be stored somewhere in your code.

Comment: I want to protect my code from hackers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can stop static analysis like that by encrypting the strings and decrypting them at runtime into a [`SecureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx).

The `SecureString` class is designed specifically to help prevent things like passwords being discoverable in memory.

However, note that it is still possible to attach a debugger to your process and see the strings, so you will need to also obfuscate using something like Dotfuscator to make it even more difficult to see the sensitive strings.

[Here is an article about some of the problems with `SecureString`](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnfa/archive/2006/11/01/securestring-redux.aspx).

Despite its drawbacks, I think it's still your best best.

Answer (score 1):

Encode it at compile time, decode at runtime? Someone may still find it since he can decompile your .exe and see the decryption algorithm but some defence > no defence.

Answer (score 1):

There's an existing implementation in the framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.securestring.aspx